# Unable to use contains for quick search in Nuxeo

Tags: postgresql, nuxeo

I am trying to use contains in Nuxeo , I want to search in all the metadata and title and content of the asset

**Example** If I search

> ten

then the search result must return

> Content22Jan.jpg
>
> tent24.jpg

.
when I use

```
select * from table where columnName like 'Con*'
```

I get the expected response

But If I do

```
select * from table where columnName like '*ten*'
```

the search does not return any result

Even

```
select * from table where columnName like '%ten%'
```

the search does not return any result
Can someone tell me how to use contains .Even if I pass part of string I should get all the results which matches the search string

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE dc:columnName LIKE '%ten%'
```

---

[Read this](https://www.nuxeo.com/blog/querying-complex-schemas-in-nuxeo-with-nxql/)

Comment: I have to make it work for ecm:fulltext , will i be able to do it @Nickname_used

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ecm:fulltext.columnName ILIKE '%ten%'`
@Swathi